# Show/Hide Login/Logout buttons based on the user state Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, authentication, visible

I Have a Login form (MVC and Knockout), I want to show or hide the Login and Logout button based on the user's state, if the user is login it should show the Logout button and vice versa.

I have tried doing it with the `visible` attribute but it's not working properly, it always shows the Login button.

I set in the code the Logout button the be visible after Login and the Login button to be visible after Logout.

```
<form id="formLogin" data-bind="submit: login">
    <label>User ID</label>
    <input class="required email form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: loginUserName" name="loginUserName" />

    <label>Password</label>
    <input class="required form-control" type="password" data-bind="value: loginPassword" name="loginPassword" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn-orange" id="buttonLogin" data-bind="visible: showLoginButton">Log In</button> <br />
    <button data-bind="click: logout, visible: showLogoutButton" class="btn btn-default" id="buttonLogout">Log Out</button>
</form>
```

My Login.js View Model:

```
var Login= function () {

/////////////// variables ///////////////
var self = this;
...
self.showLoginButton = ko.observable(true);
self.showLogoutButton = ko.observable(false);

/////////////// functions ///////////////


self.login = function (callback) {
    var loginData = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: self.loginUserName(),
        password: self.loginPassword()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../API/Token',
        data: loginData
    }).done(function (data) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem("userID", self.loginUserName());
        self.authenticate();
        self.showLogoutButton(true);
        self.showLoginButton(false);
        if (callback && typeof callback == "function")
            callback();

        self.redirect('MyPage');
    }).fail(showError);
}

self.logout = function () {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(tokenKey)
    self.showLoginButton(true);
    self.showLogoutButton(false);
 }  
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: I can't spot the error in your code. Are you sure there's no console errors? Or other code changing the display state of the elements?

Comment: Thank you, no, there is no any console errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `self.redirect('MyPage');` do? If it does a physical change of a page you don't keep the state of the observables.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it redirects the user to the main page of the website, `observable` won't keep the value when I go back to the login page?

Comment: No, it won't remember the value. You'd need some kind of storage (localstorage/sessionstorage) that would track the state of those observables but that's just creating another problem. Normally you'd use knockout as a single page application, and then the observables are always there until you dispose them. Have a look at something like this: https://sumitmaitra.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/part-3-ko-components-routes-and-hashes/

Comment: Thank you, I added a check on the `document.ready` if the user is login I set the `showLoginButton` to false and vice versa, that worked perfectly. Thank you!